# receiving an entity error after using a db.find

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm running into an entity error and I have searched for answers but I can't find one for my specific situation.

here is my code

```
[RestrictAccess(restriction = AccessRestrictions.ModifyWorkOrder)]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Audit]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,JobOrderID,StartDate,CompleteDate,jobSection,ItemID,item_qty,actual_item_qty,ComponentID,comp_qty,actual_comp_qty,PartID,part_qty,actual_part_qty,Notes,subDetail")] JODetails jODetails)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                JobOrder jo = db.JobOrders.Find(jODetails.JobOrderID);
                if (jo.hasBeenStarted)
                {

                    JODetails currentData = db.JODetails.Find(jODetails.ID);

                    int oldItemCount = currentData.item_qty != null ? (int)currentData.item_qty : 0;
                    int oldCompCount = currentData.comp_qty != null ? (int)currentData.comp_qty : 0;
                    db.Entry(jODetails).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
         }
```

It returns an error at the db.entry saying

**'Attaching an entity of type 'PIC_Program_1._0.Models.JODetails' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value**

I have noticed people have added `AsNoTracking()` to their .Where cases but I don't know how I can do something like that for a .Find

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: db.Entry(jODetails).State = EntityState.Modified; @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You need to do `db.Entry(jo).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya where? I tried putting it before the other jODetails entity modification but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Can you map the changes from jODetails to the currentData object?

Entity Framework is already tracking the entity in the currentData variable. When you attempt to track it in the db.Entry(jODetails), you are attempting to track another entity with the same id. Mapping from the user defined object to the existing object will change the values being tracked without trying to track two entities with the same Id.

Edit:

Its worth noting that the object coming from your endpoint input should probably be a DTO model instead of the DB object, but its not necessary to get a working solution.

Your solution might look something like this:

```
[RestrictAccess(restriction = AccessRestrictions.ModifyWorkOrder)]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Audit]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,JobOrderID,StartDate,CompleteDate,jobSection,ItemID,item_qty,actual_item_qty,ComponentID,comp_qty,actual_comp_qty,PartID,part_qty,actual_part_qty,Notes,subDetail")] JODetails jODetails)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        JobOrder jo = db.JobOrders.Find(jODetails.JobOrderID);
        if (jo.hasBeenStarted)
        {

            JODetails currentData = db.JODetails.Find(jODetails.ID);

            currentData.oldItemCount = currentData.item_qty;
            currentData.oldCompCount = currentData.comp_qty;

            currentData.item_qty = jODetails.item_qty;
            currentData.comp_qty = jODetails.comp_qty;
            //add any other fields, including dates, that you'd need to update.
            //This part of assigning jODetails to currentData could be simplified with AutoMapper.
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: if I move the db.Entry(jODetails).State = EntityState.Modified; to the top of the ModelState.isValid if block. It works, but I need it to come after the current data and item and comp counts so how would I accomplish this?

Comment: are you attempting to update the currentData with the jODetails? use the line 
"currentData = jODetails". Stop trying to track the user's inputed jODetails. From the logic, it looks like you are trying to overwrite currentData with jODetails, otherwise why are you trying to track jODetails when you already have currentData?

Comment: I was trying to grab the item qty value before the user changed it and save it as oldItemCount. Because futher down in the code this becomes important

Comment: @JoshFontaine before i attempt to edit my answer, do you use an AutoMapper to map one object on to another? I will use this in my edited, proposed solution if you do.

Comment: No I don't use automapper

Comment: i've updated my answer. That should stop throwing the error for you.